# Identify dp sizes in different screens

Tags: android, screen, android-custom-view, screen-resolution

if a `Custom View` of size `500w*600h` in `dp` , remain same as `px` in `(1152w*720h)px` screens of android , then what will be view's size in `dp` and `px` on screen of `(480w*600h)px` screens. And how to calculate for different size of View.

Answer (score 0):

The dp / px ratio is based on the density of the screen of the device.

I would encourage you to read the Android docs on the subject.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Each classification of screen density has a specific px multiplier associated with it i.e. mdpi = px * 1 and hdpi = px * 1.5

Here is a nice little calculator to help you make sense of it:

http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

Comment: i've read ,those articles , but was unable to convert these values in android code . that's why asked a question regarding it.

Comment: Im confused, what is it exactly that you don't understand? i have a feeling it is the density of screens, (higher density = more pixels), therefore there is no straight conversion, it depends on the screen density

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you specified your view sizes in dp(same as dip), you can use get an instance of DisplayMetrics to convert the dp to actual pixels for your current device.

A handy function you can add to a utility class for doing conversions:

```
private static float dipToPixels(Context context, int dip)
{
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, metrics);
}
```

Comment: i am talking about `Custom View` size here , context don't exist for custom views , so DisplayMetrics is of no use !

Comment: 1. By Custom View do you mean some class that extends android.view.View? 2. Are you trying to compute the correct values at Runtime OR create hard-coded values that you plug in to xml layout files based on screen size?